# Error en Ensamblador/C Segmentation Fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, linux, ensamblador, nasm

Estoy haciendo un trabajo sobre crear arboles binarios en Ensamblador llamando a las funciones desde C.
Tengo definida esta estructura en C y cuando llamó a 'crear_arbol()' a la hora de ejecutar obtengo el error "7291 Segmentation fault"

```
typedef struct nodo{
int valor;
struct nodo *izq;
struct nodo *der; } ab;

extern ab* crear_arbol();
extern int prueba(int a, int b);

int main (){
    ab* node = crear_arbol();
    int res = prueba(6,10);
    printf("%d\n", res);
    return 0;
   
}
```

Luego de muchas pruebas me di cuenta que reduciendo reduciendo la función en ensamblador a prácticamente nada seguía sucediendo, a continuación les dejo el código para que vean.

```
crear_arbol:
    push rbp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov rsp, rbp 
    pop rbp
    ret
```

Como ven la función no hace nada. La idea es que reserve memoria, asigne el numero pasado como argumento por C, y devuelva la dirección de memoria del nodo. Por ahora solo me conformo con poder devolver una simple dirección de memoria. Muchas gracias!.

Comment: Si corres tu código puedes ver que el problema está en las funciones en ensamblador. https://tio.run/##ZY3NCsJADITveYqgCFWq1IuXVZ9EkP1JdaHu1nQrqPTZ624p@JdLkvmGGb08ad33U@t01RrCbROM9avzHiDcazJUYhO41QGdN/4J1gW8ycqzgA8dF/Zx/VEMscAOpRIAUi1QM0k@Sla@yub4BIzDFFp2WAjohuSaW1IyS6fMMS01/3cO1ou0DrORpvzYSrj7rhEDTXamJsIxf5Ovi5HVHGmZTWbm4CZ5so3gXRgf6Pr@BQ Naturalmente se produce un error ya que la función `crear_arbol` no devuelve nada. Si muestras la función `prueba` podemos ver si hay algún problema ahí.

Comment: Hola @Mateo al principio devolvia una direccion de memoria y desde C trataba de imprimir el valor que tenia almacenado pero no se imprimia lo que yo esperaba, en algun momento del proceso de hacer pequeños cambios me empezó a dar el error y luego siempre que llamaba a crear_arbol me salía. La funcion 'prueba' la cree con el objetivo de ir probando si fallaba todo el codigo de ensamblador o era solo es funcion, tiene la misma estructura que crear arbol agregando las siguientes dos instrucciones: 
mov eax, edi
imul eax, esi
Solo multiplica los dos números pasados por parámetro.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a utilizar los registros de 64 bits para almacenar tu stack frame (`mov rbp, rsp`).

La pila suele estar en direcciones altas y si solo copias la parte baja del registro puede que corrompas el SP y al retornar estés accediendo a una dirección que no existe.

Para completar esta respuesta, incluyo código de ejemplo. He eliminado la función `prueba` puesto que no tiene que ver con el problema. El código C original quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void* crear_arbol();

int main (){
    void* node = crear_arbol();
    return 0;
}
```

El fichero ensamblador sería:

```
    .global crear_arbol
.text   
crear_arbol:
    push %rbp
    mov %esp, %ebp

    mov %rbp, %rsp 
    pop %rbp
```

Si llamamos `test.c` al código C y `test.s` al código en ensamblador, podemos compilar el programa de la siguiente forma:

`$ gcc -g -O0 -o test test.c test.s -znoexecstack`

El flag `-znoexecstack` simplemente elimina un warning de gcc.

Si ejecutamos ese programa reproducimos el problema del post original produciéndose un segmentation fault al ejecutarlo.

Si ejecutamos el programa en `gdb` y añadimos un breakpoint en la función `crear_arbol` podemos ver lo siguiente:

```
$ gdb ./test
(gdb) b crear_arbol
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1146: file test.s, line 4.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/SOES/01/test
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, crear_arbol () at test.s:4
4           push %rbp
(gdb) p $rbp
$1 = (void *) 0x7fffffffdec0
(gdb) p $rsp
$2 = (void *) 0x7fffffffdea8
(gdb) si
5           mov %esp, %ebp
(gdb) si
7           mov %rbp, %rsp
(gdb) p $rbp
$3 = (void *) 0xffffdea0
(gdb) p $rsp
$4 = (void *) 0x7fffffffdea0
```

Como se puede observar, tras ejecutar `mov %esp, %ebp` utilizando el comando `si` (*Step Instruction*), la parte alta del valor de `RSP` se pierde.

Sustituyendo esa instrucción por `mov %rsp, %rbp` el programa funciona correctamente.

Comment: El problema es que esa función de `crear_arbol` no está reservando memoria. No veo ningún `call` ahí.

Comment: La llamada a crear-arbol desde main se traduce en un call. Tu función main no hace nada con el valor retornado. El hecho de que no reserves memoria no tiene ningún efecto. Al menos para el código de la pregunta original.